# Change Timezone of Storefront Calendar Date Picker

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, datepicker

In checkout, I created a date picker for the delivery date. When the date picker is opened the ui-datepicker-today selects the today date of my local timezone. I cannot find a way to change the timezone. I noticed that the date picker range on the sales order grid follows the assigned timezone in the admin configuration. Do you guys have any idea how this was implemented.

[image]

[image]